# Raspberry pi4: kernel 64bit with RT extension

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi4

I followed these instructions in order to install RT extension for RPI 64bits:

[64bit RT Kernel Compilation for Raspberry Pi 4B](https://www.instructables.com/64bit-RT-Kernel-Compilation-for-Raspberry-Pi-4B-/)

The procedure works, I arrived at the end and the new kernel seems activated, but not the
RT extension!
I selected the version 5.15.31 and now "uname -a" returns:

`Linux raspberrypi 5.15.30-rt38-v8+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 28 01:46:41 CEST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

As you can see, it still PREEMPT but not with RT ..
What can happened?
Can you help me to activate real-time extension?

Thanks
Bye
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I found..
the issue was that I built and activated the kernel directly on Raspberry Pi when it works ONLY if done on Linux x86, basically on another PC and then transferred to RPI. I was convinced it was the same but it's not. Strange that finally I got a result without errors basically..

Finally I found a kernel already built here:
[Kernel Raspberry 5.4.61 64bits](https://github.com/feecat/rpi-rt)

and I followed the suggestions found here:
[raspberry-pi-4b-preempt-rt-kernel-419y-performance-test](https://lemariva.com/blog/2019/09/raspberry-pi-4b-preempt-rt-kernel-419y-performance-test)

And finally I was able to just install the kernel and see it working or RPI.
Hopefully this could help someone else.

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.61-rt37-v8+ #1 SMP PREEMPT_RT Wed Sep 9 18:58:22 CEST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Bye
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you have to do but I think isn't that clear with the instructables link is make sure the Preemption Model setting is set correctly.

So open up the config

```
make menuconfig
```

Then navigate to `General -> Preemption Model`
Then change that to realtime which should be the bottom option
Then exit save